# Azure ios application authentication error

Tags: ios, visual-studio, azure, azure-mobile-services

```
[ADAuthenticationBroker webAuthenticationDidCompleteWithURL:][379][main] 
ADALiOS [2015-06-12 12:53:00 - C9754EC2-F88F-4333-AF9F-5DBFA9A0C274]
ERROR: Error raised: 15. Additional Information: 
Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:invalid_resource 
Details:AADSTS50001:
Resource 'https://appnamemobileservice.azure-mobile.net/login/aad' 
is not registered for the account.
```

How can I fix the above error?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to register you application in AAD. If you follow [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-active-directory-authentication/) guide, it will walk you through how to set it up. If you've done this already, check your settings. It is implying that you've not set something up correctly. Try making `https://appnamemobileservice.azure-mobile.net/login/aad` your only callback, if it's not already.